# Create a unique div for all posts in a Query search

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently working on the search function for my Wordpress website.

I use the following code to get the search result:

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); 
while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : 
    $the_query -> the_post(); 
?>

<div id="searchresult">
<p style="height: 10; margin-top: 0px;"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(170,100) ); ?>
</div>

<?php 
endwhile;
?>
```

This creates a new div called "searchresult" containing a title and thumbnail for all 5 posts.
I can therefore call "searchresult" to make changes too all of them.

However, I need to be able to control and change them individually rather than all at once.
I would therefore like to know how I can assign a unique div with a unique id for each post in my search result.
Ex searchresult1, searchresult2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `class` instead; for example:

```
<div class="searchresult">
    <!-- more code -->
</div>
```

But if you need to use `ID` then just use the `$post->ID` like this:

```
<div id="searchresult-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
    <!-- more code -->
</div>
```

You may also use `<?php the_id()?>`. In this case, all `$post->ID`s will be unique and the result will be something like this:

```
<div id="searchresult-101>
    <!-- more code -->
</div>

<div id="searchresult-102>
    <!-- more code -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked just like I wanted.